# Specific HTML title attribute value making element disappear

Tags: html, attributes

`<a href="#" title="Back to Top">test link</a>`

My `<a>` tag disappears when the value of my title attribute is "Back to Top"... If I change "Back to Top" in ANY way, the  tag re-appears.It's specifically the value "Back to Top" that makes the element disappear. This happens with ANY element I try it on. This only happens on my computer, and not my laptop. I've been learning Git and GitHub recently pushing and pulling this same file between my computer and laptop & i'm thinking that has something to do with it... Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: I don't think there's any sinister hidden function for hiding (specifically) "Back toTop" in any browser I know of, so - going to need a bit more detail - which web framework are you using (if any) ? Which browser was causing the issue ? If you use the browser's debug tools do you see the anchor element in the DOM ?

Comment: Pure HTML, Chrome. I just found the problem: A chrome extension called Adblocker for Chrome - NoAds version 3.2.0.23. I disabled the extension and the element returned! They just updated the extension to 3.3 today, so if anyone even tries to replicate what happened to me, it might not work, as i was on v3.2.0.23. On my computer, and v3.63.3.3 on my laptop(which is why my laptop wasn't showing problems) I'm glad i found the fix.